# How do I make use of the GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

I am not sure what it means when it tells me to use:

GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha

How can I use that API call to retrieve the information I am looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha

- `GET` is the HTTP method to use in order to invoke this API endpoint.
- `:owner` is the name of the user or organization (eg. `octocat` is the name of a **[user](https://github.com/octocat)**).
- `:repo` is the name of a repository owned by the chosen user or organization (eg. the `octocat` user shares the **[Spoon-Knife](https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife)** repository)
- `:sha` is the 40 bytes long **[unique identifier](https://schacon.github.io/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html)** of a Git Object
- You have to prepend you call with the **[root endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/#root-endpoint)** -> `https://api.github.com`.

Considering this, in order to show

- The commit **bb4cc8d3b2e14b3af5df699876dd4ff3acd00b7f**
- In the repository **Spoon-Knife**
- Belonging to the user **octocat**

One would issue a **GET** Http call to the following url

https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/commits/bb4cc8d3b2e14b3af5df699876dd4ff3acd00b7f

For instance, using the following curl command...

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/commits/bb4cc8d3b2e14b3
af5df699876dd4ff3acd00b7f
```

...will return the following Json payload

```
{
  "sha": "bb4cc8d3b2e14b3af5df699876dd4ff3acd00b7f",
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "name": "The Octocat",
      "email": "octocat@nowhere.com",
      "date": "2014-02-04T22:38:36Z"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "The Octocat",
      "email": "octocat@nowhere.com",
      "date": "2014-02-12T23:18:55Z"
    },
    "message": "Create styles.css and updated README",

...[snipped for brevity]...

      "patch": "@@ -0,0 +1,17 @@\n+* {\n+  margin:0px;\n+  padding:0px;\n+}\n+\n+#octocat {\n+  display: block;\n+  width:384px;\n+  margin: 50px auto;\n+}\n+\n+p {\n+  display: block;\n+  width: 400px;\n+  margin: 50px auto;\n+  font: 30px Monaco,\"Courier New\",\"DejaVu Sans Mono\",\"Bitstream Vera Sans Mono\",monospace;\n+}"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Update

As rightfully pointed at by **[@matsjoyce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3946766/matsjoyce)**, numerous libraries abstract this low level operations and expose a more user friendly interface. Most of them are listed at **https://developer.github.com/libraries/**

Comment: You could also note that there are tons of wrappers for this, such as PyGithub, depending on what language the requests are being done from.

Comment: @matsjoyce Good catch! I've just updated the answer to add this.