# How to get the commits from all the repositories from a Github's organization

Tags: git, github, github-api

So I want to gather from all the repositories within an organization the commits that have been done to each repository. So i've read about the branches. The pagination everything. But still cant quite get it. So about the command

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits`

by ":owner" does it mean the one that did the commit or the one that owns the repo? I mean have any one else done such thing? To gather all the commits? What are the steps one should take to achieve such thing.

Thank you guys!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26194434/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106119/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-commits-for-many-users-organizations-using-the-g

Comment: so I am using /repos/:owner/:repo/commits. But I just get one object. "sha". But I am sure in that repo more members have done commits. So how can I get those?

Answer (score 0):

#### Who is the owner in a GitHub API call?

> by ":owner" does it mean the one that did the commit or the one that owns the repo?

To answer your first question, the owner refers to a repository owner, which can be an organization or user. To get the value, you can visit the repo at github.com. You'll see the information you need in the URL bar. In the example below, `firebase` is the owner value you would use in your GET, while `snippets-web` is the repo value.

```
URL https://github.com/:owner/:repo
URL https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web

GET /repos/OWNER/REPO/commits
GET /repos/firebase/snippets-web/commits
```

---

#### How to List a Committer's Commits to a Repo

If you're required to fetch the commits directly from the GitHub API, you can find the latest way to do that using this API doc: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits.

If direct use of the API is not a requirement, the `gh` command offers an alternative some might find friendlier:

```
gh search commits [<query>] [flags]
```

The command offers quite a few flags that may serve your purpose, including the `committer` flag. For more information, see https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_search_commits.